Don't change the score back and forth when voting on a vote-locked post
When voting on a vote-locked post, we get this error-message:

You last voted on this question Sep 21 at 4:29. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited.

OK, fair enough. But the score shouldn't change momentarily change, even if it looks cute.
Many users will think the vote really has been changed, and will then close the page. They will not necessarily stick around to notice it getting changed back again to the original vote. Nor will they notice the message.
And even it if they do, the price of "being cute" in just not worth the confusion it creates.
The message should still appear, but the post score should stay rock-solid, not going down and then back up, or up and then back down, even if it looks cute.
Even if the restoration is changed from one second later to a half second later.

I don't think it has anything to do with "being cute", it's more likely just an order of operations.

It was probably indeed not intentionally designed to be cute, but it is arguably a bug/a sloppy implementation if the score appears to change while it is locked, so it would be good if that was fixed.

This is not a "bug", nor something that can be fixed without significantly affecting normal voting.

I agree this can be addressed. However, I don't really agree it's such as huge an issue as presented here.

A long string of comments has been removed that discussed possible implementation details, concluding that preflight client-side validation, as requested here, could be implemented for the majority of cases if the server provided more information (e.g., when the vote was cast) on page load (though server-side validation would still be required, and it would still be possible to see this issue occur in some edge cases).  While the discussion was not inherently off-topic, it was getting unnecessarily argumentative and starting to add more noise than useful information (which I've summarized).

I don't see why this obvious UX improvement is even slightly controversial.

The reason this happens is because of the several steps it takes to submit (and render) the vote.

The user clicks the vote arrow.
The website renders the changed vote count and highlights the clicked vote button.
The website sends a request to the server, to register the new vote.
This request returns to the client, and then the client knows the vote was invalid, and resets the vote counter and button.

To fix this, you would need to move point 2 to the last position, meaning you're introducing a delay between clicking the vote, and the vote showing, for all users on all votes.
This will without a doubt result in users casting their votes twice, as they're not seeing the UI update.
So now you end up with users double-casting their votes, an overall usability degradation for the much more common usecase.
(At least double-casting an upvote doesn't really do anything, as downvoting requires a different payload)
TLD;RD:
It's not a bug. It's a consequence of having to validate votes server-side, with (in my opinion) no good workaround.
As Thom A mentioned, any client-side validation can easily be circumvented by just changing your system clock.

The vote count could be replaced by a spinner icon (indicating a still running process) and only display the vote count again (updated or not) after the server has answered the request. While I understand that the current system has been in place since years, I still understand that people can be frustrated or get confused by the current behavior. As noted by VLAZ, in the comments, this is nothing new in the industry.

Why can't the client already know that the post is vote-locked?

@Lino that's significantly worse UX in a significant majority of cases. Not an option, in my opinion.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban that vote lock is based on the time you last voted, which is information that the client (currently) does not have access to. Even if that information were available, that would easily be circumvented by changing the system clock, so not that robust.

@Cerbrus why not tell the client?

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban tell the client what?

@Cerbrus either the lock status, or the information necessary to know the lock status. Why shouldn't the server do that?

As banned user said, the workaround of telling when votes are locked seems fine. “Users who have the wrong system clock could circumvent the check therefore it’s not robust” is nonsense logic. If their clock is wrong, that’s their own problem, but 99.9% of machines have their clocks frequently automatically synchronized. Habitual dismissiveness of reasonable suggestions for contrived reasons is one of the most toxic patterns of behaviour on Meta. The sites already dead so it doesn’t really matter, but if we actually wanted to attract a new users, this would have to stop.

What if ATMs first opened the door to hand you the cash, then changed their minds and shut the door before you could get your hand back out? What if electronic voting booths first tallied your vote for candidate B, before checking if you were indeed registered to vote in the first place, and only then removing your vote, ah... but you already pressed X before it could correct the problem, etc.

What happens in my case, as I only upvote people, because I am so nice, is that I don't notice I have already upvoted something, despite the colored circle, so I upvote again, only to be shocked that the number goes down instead of up... of course, because my second click is assumed to be trying to remove my first click (that I made months ago.) Anyway, if it stayed rock solid, I would have one less shock.

Comparing internet points to money and actual consequential votes is disingenuous. They're not similar. In my opinion, UX is much more important that security here.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban: Lock status: That changes on a timer, so would require a websocket, for significant additional load to SE. The information necessary: For the 3rd time, just changing the user's system clock circumvents that. It's not robust, and doesn't prevent the issue OP describes.

You are right in claiming that there is no way to eliminate server-side validation and replace it entirely with client-side validation. However, client-side checks could certainly be put into place to check things like whether the post is locked, and, if so, don't change the score. It would be a refinement of the current implementation, which guesses that the action will succeed, but double-checks with the server. By adding logic that checks on the client side first, it would increase the odds of the client-side guess being correct. Now, whether this is worth doing is a different question.

@Cerbrus nobody cares if there's a two second window within which the server knows the post is locked and the client doesn't, and people voting within that window receive an error. That's a non-problem. The problem is that right now the window is infinity seconds wide.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban No, that window is as wide as it takes for the server to respond to a vote. Let's not exaggerate the issue, here.

@Cerbrus I'm talking about the window where the user can vote in order to see a revert, not the window between the user voting and seeing the revert. If the server specified whether the user can vote or not, that would lower it to one page refresh. If the server also sent how long until the user can't vote, that would lower it to some multiple of network round trips. Both are much smaller than infinity. The app server already has to look up how the user has voted, so it wouldn't add more database fetches.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban Your whole argument is about some "infinite" window that doesn't exist. "where the user can vote in order to see a revert, not the window between the user voting and seeing the revert" You've got to be clearer that that, because I have no idea what windows you're talking about there, if you're not describing the same thing twice, there.
